# Paypal API (NVP) TransactionSearch giving error 10004 - Start Date is invalid

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, nvp

Okay, so the following code is giving me the above error "Start date is invalid". Even when I have verified from various sources that it is a valid and well formatted start date. The res of the code has no problem since it is successfully returning the correct balance. I have searched every where but can't find a solution to this. Please help. Thanks!

```
class Paypal
{
/**
 * API Version
 */
const VERSION = 51.0;

/**
 * List of valid API environments
 * @var array
 */
private $allowedEnvs = array(
    'beta-sandbox',
    'live',
    'sandbox'
);

/**
 * Config storage from constructor
 * @var array
 */
private $config = array();

/**
 * URL storage based on environment
 * @var string
 */
private $url;

/**
 * Build PayPal API request
 * 
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @param string $signature
 * @param string $environment
 */
public function __construct($username, $password, $signature, $environment = 'live')
{
    if (!in_array($environment, $this->allowedEnvs)) {
    throw new Exception('Specified environment is not allowed.');
    }
    $this->config = array(
    'username'    => $username,
    'password'    => $password,
    'signature'   => $signature,
    'environment' => $environment
    );
}

/**
 * Make a request to the PayPal API
 * 
 * @param  string $method API method (e.g. GetBalance)
 * @param  array  $params Additional fields to send in the request (e.g. array('RETURNALLCURRENCIES' => 1))
 * @return array
 */
public function call($method, array $params = array())
{
    $fields = $this->encodeFields(array_merge(
    array(
        'METHOD'    => $method,
        'VERSION'   => self::VERSION,
        'USER'      => $this->config['username'],
        'PWD'       => $this->config['password'],
        'SIGNATURE' => $this->config['signature']
    ),
    $params
    ));

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->getUrl());
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (!$response) {
    throw new Exception('Failed to contact PayPal API: ' . curl_error($ch) . ' (Error No. ' . curl_errno($ch) . ')');
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    parse_str($response, $result);
    return $this->decodeFields($result);
}

/**
 * Prepare fields for API
 * 
 * @param  array  $fields
 * @return array
 */
private function encodeFields(array $fields)
{
    return array_map('urlencode', $fields);
}

/**
 * Make response readable
 * 
 * @param  array  $fields
 * @return array
 */
private function decodeFields(array $fields)
{
    return array_map('urldecode', $fields);
}

/**
 * Get API url based on environment
 * 
 * @return string
 */
private function getUrl()
{
    if (is_null($this->url)) {
    switch ($this->config['environment']) {
        case 'sandbox':
        case 'beta-sandbox':
        $this->url = "https://api-3t.".$this->config['environment'].".paypal.com/nvp";
        break;
        default:
        $this->url = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp';
    }
    }
    return $this->url;
}
}
$paypal = new Paypal('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');



print_r($paypal->call('TransactionSearch', array("STARTDATE"=>"2016-02-24T00:00:00Z")));
```

Comment: The correct sample should be :  STARTDATE = 2016-05-25T00:00:00Z . refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your call to `$this->encodeFields()` (inside of `call()`) is causing your parameter values to be double-`urlencode()`'d.  `$this->encodeFields()` is calling `urlencode()` on each of the elements in your `$fields` array; however, `http_build_query()` does this for you automatically.  Therefore, you're probably ending up with `STARTDATE=2016-02-24T00%253A00%253A00Z` in your call to PayPal, when it should actually be `STARTDATE=2016-02-24T00%3A00%3A00Z`.

Comment: this makes sense. Will give it a try